# Given a pandas dataframe, is there an easy way to print out a command to generate it?

Tags: python, pandas

After running some commands I have a pandas dataframe, eg.:

```
>>> print df
   B  A
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  3
4  5  4
```

I would like to print this out so that it produces simple code that would recreate it, eg.:

```
DataFrame([[2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4]],columns=['B','A'],index=[1,2,3,4])
```

I tried pulling out each of the three pieces (data, columns and rows):

```
[[e for e in row] for row in df.iterrows()]
[c for c in df.columns]
[r for r in df.index]
```

but the first line fails because `e` is not a value but a `Series`.

Is there a pre-build command to do this, and if not, how do I do it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Woody Pride's approach, here is the full solution I am using.  It handles hierarchical indices and index names.

```
from types import MethodType
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex

def _gencmd(df, pandas_as='pd'):
    """
    With this addition to DataFrame's methods, you can use:
        df.command()
    to get the command required to regenerate the dataframe df.
    """
    if pandas_as:
        pandas_as += '.'
    index_cmd = df.index.__class__.__name__
    if type(df.index)==MultiIndex:
        index_cmd += '.from_tuples({0}, names={1})'.format([i for i in df.index], df.index.names)
    else:
        index_cmd += "({0}, name='{1}')".format([i for i in df.index], df.index.name)
    return 'DataFrame({0}, index={1}{2}, columns={3})'.format([[xx for xx in x] for x in df.values],
                                                                pandas_as,
                                                                index_cmd,
                                                                [c for c in df.columns])


DataFrame.command = MethodType(_gencmd, None, DataFrame)
```

I have only tested it on a few cases so far and would love a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of the data frame in array format by calling `df.values`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4]],columns=['B','A'],index=[1,2,3,4])
arrays = df.values
cols = df.columns
index = df.index
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arrays, columns = cols, index = index)
```

Comment: Great, this is just what I was missing.  So I have solved my problem using: 
`def _gencmd(df):
    return 'DataFrame({0}, index={1}, columns={2})'.format([[xx for xx in x] for x in df.values], [i for i in df.index], [c for c in df.columns])
from types import MethodType
DataFrame.gencmd = MethodType(_gencmd, None, DataFrame)`. After this, `df.gencmd` gives me the command required to regenerate the dataframe `df`.

Comment: Actually it's `df.gencmd()`

Comment: And to make it work with hierarchical indices, you need `index={1}({2})` with the extra argument to `format`: `type(df.index).__name__`